# Benzalkonium chloride breakdown time

Tags: organic-chemistry, surfactants

[image]

I wonder if and how long (approximately) it will take for benzalkonium chloride (shown above; $n = 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18$) to breakdown (degrade fully or partly) in a closed water loop with continuous flow and a volume of approximately $1.5\ \mathrm{L}$ distilled water.

The concentration will be around $2\ \mathrm{ppm}$ to $10\ \mathrm{ppm}$.

UV and general light will be kept to a minimum but can't be fully shut out. The temperature will flucturate between $19\ ^\circ\mathrm{C}$ to $50\ ^\circ\mathrm{C}$.

Thank You!

Comment: Are you trying to break it down asap or keep it active for as long as possible? It is very stable under neutral or slightly pH, but it can decompose in 2M NaOH. See the following reference for details (*Journal of Liquid Chromatography & Related Technologies*, **2012**, *35:2*, 231-239, [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10826076.2011.597072))

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, didn't notice the question had been answered until now. I am trying to keep it active as long as possible to use it as an biocide in water. I don't know if or when to add more to compensate for degradation.